# ¿Cómo instalar Bootstrap5 en Laravel 6?

Tags: laravel, bootstrap

estoy tratando de instalar la verion 5 de Bootstrap en un proyecto hecho en Laravel 6. Para esto usé el comando `php artisan ui bootstrap` que aparece en la documentación oficial, pero este instala la versión 4.6 de Bootstrap y lo hace descargando todo el código en el archivo "public/css/app.css".

¿Alguién sabe si existe un comando para descargar la versión 5 de Bootstrap o si hay otra aceptable de hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Probaste cambiar la versión en el archivo package.json?

Comment: Hola, cambié en el archivo package.json a la version 5.0.1 y corrí nuevamente el comando `php artisan ui bootstrap` y `npm install && npm run dev`

Cuando terminó el proceso en la terminal volvió a la version 4.0.0 en el archivo package.json y a la version 4.6 en el archivo "public/css/app.css"

Comment: Es que si corres de nuevo `php artisan ui bootstrap` va a volver a lo anterior. Me refería a que cambies la versión de bootstrap a la 5 y corras solamente `npm install` y `npm run dev`. Nota que posiblemente tengas que eliminar el archivo `package-lock.json` y el directorio `node_modules`

Comment: O mejor aún, elimina las dependencias que trae laravel/ui y corre `npm install bootstrap`

Comment: Buena noche, disculpa mi ignorancia, pero ¿cómo elimino las dependencias que trae laravel/ui?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que sea más claro, empecemos desde el principio...

Creas un proyecto Laravel en la versión 6:

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "6.*"
```

Y lo levantas con:

```
php artisan serve
```

Esto iniciará un servidor de desarrollo en http://localhost:8000, donde podrás ver la página de bienvenida de Laravel 6.

Luego instalas las dependencias de front-end y las compilas:

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

A continuación instalas [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/download/#package-managers):

```
npm install bootstrap @popperjs/core --save-dev
```

Dentro del directorio `resources/scss/` modifica el archivo `app.scss` para importar los estilos:

```
// resources/scss/app.scss 

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Dentro del directorio `resources/js/` modifica el archivo `bootstrap.js` para importar el módulo de js:

```
// resources/js/bootstrap.js 

window._ = require("lodash");
import "bootstrap";
//...
```

Vuelve a compilar:

```
npm run dev
```

Modifica la vista de bienvenida que trae laravel para cargar el js y los estilos compilados:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel 6 y Bootstrap 5</title>

        <link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>


    <script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Pronto, ya tienes Bootstrap 5 instalado y funcionado. Puedes agregar el html con las clases de Bootstrap 5.

Por ejemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Laravel 6 y Bootstrap 5</title>

        <link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
        <header class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center py-3 mb-4 border-bottom">
            <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-dark text-decoration-none">
                <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use></svg>
                <span class="fs-4">Simple header</span>
            </a>

            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Features</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Pricing</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">FAQs</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>
    </div>

    <script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Te mostrará algo así en el navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Bonus**: Hice estos pasos para probarlo, ya que no recordaba cómo venía la versión 6 de Laravel por defecto. Puedes ver los cambios en el código que te fuí mencionado en los commits de este repositorio [instalar-Bootstrap_5-en-Laravel_6](https://github.com/porloscerros/instalar-Bootstrap_5-en-Laravel_6/commits/main).